# OpenCL: Wrong Values using CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR

Tags: opencl

I've written the following code unfortunately

```
//host
float filter[9] = 
    { 1, 2, 1,
      0, 0, 0,
     -1, -2, -1
     };
cl::Buffer Filter(m_prog.getContext(), 
      CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, 9 * sizeof(float), filter);
//..
//device
foo(..., __constant float * filter,...)
{
printf("%i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i\n", filter[0], filter[1], filter[2], 
      filter[3], filter[4], filter[5], filter[6], filter[7], filter[8]);
```

I get the following output

> 0 1072693248 0 1073741824 0 1072693248 0 0 0

What i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use wrong printf conversion specifier. Correctly that should be:

```
printf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f\n", filter[0], filter[1], filter[2], 
  filter[3], filter[4], filter[5], filter[6], filter[7], filter[8]);
```